# Check if Express App is configured to use HTTPS

Tags: node.js, express, https, protocols

I've figured out how to configure Express API to utilize https, but I have a "globals" check for some variables including things like `Is_Node` or `Is_HTTPS` because I run my source code both client and server side.

First thing that failed was checking `location.protocol` because `location` is undefined (in Node). I figured I could use `Is_Node` to define how I check `Is_HTTPS` and NOT use `location`. But, I can't seem to figure out how to get it to check if https or http.

This check is done during startup, not during a `req` so I can't use `req.foo`.

Ideally, I don't want to set a boolean in the `app.js` as the point of my `globals` check is to be able to run independent of how the server/client is configured and return the results.

I'm using the Express template and here is how I'd configure the server for http/https:

```
var https = require('https')
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/app/ssl/key.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/app/ssl/crt.crt'),
};
var port = 3000
app.set('port', port);
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
```

---

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 3000
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

in my `globals` check I've got the following working, but not sure what to do next..

```
var app = module.exports.app
var server = module.exports.server
```

Update: I'm pretty close, here is what I got, but something I don't like is it requires hard coding the port. In this case, I can get away with it, but I'd prefer if it checked the local NodeJS instance and could figure out the Express port somehow..

I'm also up for better solutions, so I'll leave this and perhaps post as an answer in a day or two..

---

```
function getGlobal() {
  return typeof self !== "undefined"
    ? self
    : typeof window !== "undefined"
    ? window
    : typeof global !== "undefined"
    ? global
    : undefined;
}

var g = getGlobal();

var FUNCS = {};
g.FUNCS = FUNCS;
FUNCS.Dev_Bools = {};

if (typeof window === "undefined") {
  FUNCS.Dev_Bools.Is_NodeJS_Mode = true;
} else {
  FUNCS.Dev_Bools.Is_NodeJS_Mode = false;
  var module = {};
  g.module = module;
}

if (FUNCS.Dev_Bools.Is_NodeJS_Mode == true) {
  var port = 3000;
  var https = require("https");
  var options = {
    host: "localhost",
    port: port,
    path: "/",
    method: "GET",
    rejectUnauthorized: false, //Set to false to pass w/ bad SSL certs
    requestCert: true,
    agent: false,
  };
  var request = https.request(options, function (req) {
    FUNCS.Dev_Bools.HTTPS_Mode = true;
    console.log("FUNCS.Dev_Bools.HTTPS_Mode:" + FUNCS.Dev_Bools.HTTPS_Mode);
  });
  request.on("error", function (err) {
    FUNCS.Dev_Bools.HTTPS_Mode = false;
    console.log("FUNCS.Dev_Bools.HTTPS_Mode:" + FUNCS.Dev_Bools.HTTPS_Mode);
  });
  request.end();
} else {
  if (location.protocol === "https:") {
    FUNCS.Dev_Bools.HTTPS_Mode = true;
  } else {
    FUNCS.Dev_Bools.HTTPS_Mode = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the usecase for to knowing if Express is configured to run with HTTP/s? If "Is_HTTPS" triggers some logicical differentiation, perhaps there is a different way to make that check. Asked a different way, what triggers your ExpressJS app to start the HTTP server with HTTPS?

Comment: @Alan I tend not to want alternatives to how to accomplish task tbh, but I understand the thinking when answering as I've offered them. In this case, lets say the goal is to be able to source globals client and server side without crashing/errors and get results so I can expect things to be defined later on.

Comment: @Alan as far as your second statement, "what triggers ExpressJS to start HTTP/S", its how I configure the server? The goal is that `globals` can be sourced from any website/nodejs instance and provide some variables without me having to remember the hacky ways to tell if I'm in `IE` or `Edge` or `NodeJS` and be able to source the same code.